# Discord.js Ping Command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was trying to make a ping command for my bot here is my Code

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === '+ping') {  
    message.channel.send(`Latency is ${m.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}ms. API Latency is ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms`);
  }
});
```

However I end up getting the following error

```
C:\Users\ujjwa\Desktop\All Disc\Test all\index.js:236
    message.channel.send(`Latency is ${m.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}ms. API Latency is ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms`);
                                     ^

ReferenceError: m is not defined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lol\Desktop\All Disc\Test all\index.js:236:42)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\lol\Desktop\All Disc\Test all\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\lol\Desktop\All Disc\Test all\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\lol\Desktop\All Disc\Test all\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\lol\Desktop\All Disc\Test all\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\lol\Desktop\All Disc\Test all\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\lol\Desktop\All Disc\Test all\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\lol\Desktop\All Disc\Test all\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:797:20)
```

Can you help me out?

Comment: Did you mean `message` instead of `m`? Or where did you define `m`?

Comment: oh thank you i meant message over there

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to use `Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp` to get the latency.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === '+ping') {  
    message.channel.send(`Latency is ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms. API Latency is ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms`);
  }
});
```

Comment: This will only get the time between the API and the bot. Normally a ping will count the time it takes to send from A to B and back to A. Knowing the latency one way is still useful, however comparing it to other pings will be misleading.

Comment: We can, of course implement such a suggestion to the answer above.

Comment: Idk what ur on about tbh, it shows api latency and latency of the bot -- one that the user will experience

Comment: I am merely pointing out that a "ping" generally refers to the time network packets travel from a source, to a destination, and back to the source. Comparing the remote time with the local time will show the delay between them, but not necessarily back and forth.

Comment: On Discord, "ping" refers to latency.

Comment: In regards to what you're on about, `<Client>.ws.ping` is the closest you get to what you're describing, and that was already included in the answer I had given

Comment: And, you're approaching this from a much more... advanced point of view. Most of the people on Discord who interact with Discord bots only really care about how "slow" the bot is to produce a response. On the discord.js docs, `<Client>.ws.ping` only means "The average ping of all WebSocketShards" [Source](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/WebSocketManager?scrollTo=ping) which doesn't seem to answer your question

Comment: That's fair. On that note, wouldn't `<Client>.ws.ping` be the most accurate to display as the realistic latency of the bot, and render the timestamp calculation redundant?

Comment: It would, but the timestamp calculation actually helps give an average of what the bot's users are experiencing. Eg if your bot has a slow DB connection, using commands will take longer but the PING from `<Client>.ws.ping` would be a lot smaller, confusing many people. Even in the official discord.js server, they recommend displaying both pings, especially since `<Client>.ws.ping` only takes into account websocket latency.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I guess I was under the assumption that the API latency would impact the time it takes the bot to submit a message (isn't that a POST request to the API?), but I have seen the API latency show a much higher number which is indeed confusing.

Comment: Ikr. That is also what confuses me, but it is what it is. From what I've gathered, client.ws.ping is in direct relation to the WebSocket connection and the timestamp calculation is in relation to your process' efficiency [getting a response to the user]. Then again, the ping cmd only sends a message whereas other cmds may be more memory heavy and may require more time to compute.

Comment: I get negative latency with this code `Latency is -60ms.`

Answer (score 8):

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === prefix + 'ping') {
  message.channel.send('Loading data').then (async (msg) =>{
    msg.delete()
    message.channel.send(`Latency is ${msg.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}ms. API Latency is ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms`);
  })
  }
});
```

Comment: +1. Not sure why this answer was downvoted. This is more accurate because it tests both ways, as ping should. Comparing `now` with a message's timestamp will only test one-way latency.

Answer (score 1):

I use this As My Ping Command (Sorry if I make Any Kind of Mistake, I just learned JavaScript in the last 2 Days)

```
module.exports={
    name:'ping',
    description: "Command ini digunakan untuk Ping",
    execute(message, args){
        message.channel.send(`Latency is ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms`);
        }
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use .then() to have m:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === '+ping') {  
message.channel.send('pinging').then(m => {
    m.edit(`Latency is ${m.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}ms. API Latency is ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms`);
  });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === '+ping') {  
    message.channel.send(`Latency is ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms. API Latency is ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms`);
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I used a code where its date now and a message created timestamp and a api ping.

```
module.exports = {
  name: "ping",
  category: "info",
  description: "Get bot ping :/",
  usage: "ping",
  run: (client, message) => {
    message.channel.send(`**:ping_pong:Latency is ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms. API Latency is ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms.:ping_pong:**`);
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score -2):

For me I used this it seemed to work for me!

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    discription: 'description',
    execute(message, args) {
        message.channel.send(` | Latency is: **${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms.**`);
    },
};
```