# How to create discord.js ping command?

Tags: discord.js

I am using discord.js version 12. I have checked the docs already, it's kind of confusing.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const client = new Discord.Client()
client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

This is my current code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js Ping Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63411268/discord-js-ping-command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple ping command

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.content === '!ping') {
    message.channel.send("Pinging ...")
      .then((msg) => {
        msg.edit("Pong: " + (Date.now() - msg.createdTimestamp) + "ms")
      });
  }
})

client.login("TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy command to do ! We are doing to make things nice and beautiful !

now you create a message event, and if the message is "!ping" it will replies with the bot ping ! We are gonna to use the class "MessageEmbed" from the discord.js module. This class permit us to create nice and slick embeds !

Also, instead of requiring all the discord.js module, you can get only
classes from it like that in the example below !

Also put the `client.login(process.env.TOKEN)` at the end of your main/index.js file

```js
// Requiring the client and message embed objects from discordjs module
const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

// New discordjs client
const client = new Client(); // Name it as you want

// Ready event !
client.on("ready", () => {
 // Sends something to the console to say that the bot is ready to work !
 console.log("The bot is connected !")
});

client.on("message", message => {
 // Ping command !
 if(message.content === "!ping") {
   // New embed for the bot ping !
   const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(`** My ping is : **\`${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms\``)
   // Now we send the embed to our channel !
   message.channel.send(embed)
 } // End of our command code !
})

// Now logs in the bot using your token (keep secret !)
client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.content === '!ping') {
    message.channel.send("Latency is ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms`")
      });
  }
})
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with embeds, I prefer something like this.

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "ping",
    description: "Sends the ping of the bot.",
    usage: ".pi or .ping",
    aliases: ["pi", "PI", "PING"],

    
    execute(client, message, args, cmd, Discord) {
        let member = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author
        let avatar = member.displayAvatarURL({size: 1024})
        
        const newPingEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        
        //.setTitle(`:stopwatch: The Ping Meter`) of choice
        .addFields(
            {name: `:robot: The Bot's Latency`, value: `**${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}**ms.`},
            {name: `:desktop: The API's Latency`, value: `**${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}**ms.`}
        )
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setFooter(`Requested by ${member.username}`, avatar)
        .setTimestamp()
        
        message.channel.send(newPingEmbed);
    }
}
```

[Example of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f81lu.png)