# Is there any way to make a ping command in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

you might know me due to my discord.py question. this time, i want to know how to do it in discord.js. if you haven't read it, I basically dont know how to make a discord ping command in discord.js. thanks a lot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js Ping Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63411268/discord-js-ping-command)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** This Question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63411268/discord-js-ping-command).

Get the message ping:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === '!ping') {  
    message.channel.send(`Ping: ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms`);
  }
});
```

Latency ping:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === '!ping') {  
    message.channel.send(`API Latency is ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms`);
  }
});
```

Check [this](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/faq.html#how-do-i-check-the-bot-s-ping) out in the [Discord.js Guide](https://discordjs.guide/#before-you-begin).