# How do you make a discord bot tell ping?

Tags: discord, discord.js

How do you make a discord bot tell ping? I'm trying to make a ping command.

Will subtracting the "createdAt" and the current time work? Is the "createdAt" when the user sent the message, or when the server receives it? The discord.js documentation does not tell me.

Comment: Your question does not include any sign of research. It's more of a code request, please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) before asking any other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this. It’s very easy to find it on internet.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === '+ping') {  
    message.channel.send(`Latency is ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms. API Latency is ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms`);
  }
});
```

Copied code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63411714/9776840) post.

Comment: that took the date that is now and the date the message has been sent and subtracted it but I don't need that

Comment: You can remove the ```${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}``` and the text. It’s will not broke your bot

Comment: If you remove this code, you will just get the API ping and not your bot

Comment: But if you want to have only the bot ping, just remove ```${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}```

Comment: @Jmooroof if my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark

Answer (score 0):

The ping you mentioned results in message response time. If you want this, you can do it like this. But, if you want the API ping (the response time of API), you can insert as "client.ws.ping".

```
client.on('message', message => {
  let messageping = Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp;
  let apiping = client.ws.ping;

  // Dividing and putting the unit of time:

  if(messageping > 1000) messageping = (messageping / 1000) + "s"
  else messageping += "ms";
  if (message.content.startsWith("ping")) {  
    message.channel.send(`**Pong!**\nSever latency: ${messageping}\nAPI latency: ${apiping}`);
  };
});
```