# Ping has a negative value (Discord.js v13)

Tags: javascript, discord.js, delay, ping

Ping outputs a negative value. I consulted the answer for [a correct ping statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63411714/16410937), and nothing seems to go wrong.

My ping command :

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name: "ping",
    description: "Test Ping to Bot",

    async run (client, message, args) {
        console.log(`${message.createdAt} | ${message.author.tag} ${message.author} : ${message}`)
        const ping = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('** PING PONG! **')
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        .addFields(
            { name: 'Độ trễ của Bot', value: `${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms` },
            { name: 'Độ trễ của API', value: `${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms`, inline: true },
        )
        .setTimestamp()   
        message.channel.send({embeds : [ping]});
    }
}
```

Output :

[image: ping]

*discord.js 13.0.0-dev.t1628035429.00d5cee*

Comment: i see you use `message.createdAt` and `message.createdTimestamp`. i dont know if this is intentional and if it is causing the problem but maybe this helps

Comment: i use `message.createdAt`  for console log only.

Comment: Weird... [Can't reproduce](https://i.imgur.com/EgQb9a9.png).

Comment: it can be that the time your computer uses (the one that runs this script) is not synced with the server time of discord.

Answer (score 0):

Fatal amateur mistake. Never use Date.now() with non-local timestamps unless you can somehow guarantee that the server time and your computer time are exactly the same.